# Industry Term for "Eye-Catching"

Tags: terminology, document-design

I am thinking there is an industry term for an element or animation that brings attention to another, or is itself inherently eye catching.

e.g.

> Anyway, my general concern is that the transition to toolbar
>   navigation is just not that **eye-catching**.
>
> The transition back to the doc is even less **eye-catching**.

Comment: Just so you know, in case you don't receive satisfactory answers here, there's a tag for "single-word-requests" on [english.se] that may help to solicit some other descriptive words. If you do ask there, including the example sentences you have here will help provide the appropriate context. I'm not sure of any decidedly standard terms, but your examples seem related to the topic of visual hierarchy. In your examples, I'd probably just use adjectives like "prominent" or "pronounced". Perhaps "immersive" may satisfy some uses.

Comment: I don't like the term, but many managers and product owners like to ask designers to make it 'pop', as in to make something stand out and wow the user or customer :D

Comment: I am with you @MichaelLai, I am not much of a fan of pop either, but it might work for this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common term used when giving feedback for designs. But it is by no means an industry term. Personally, like @Michael Lai mentioned, I don't like it either. Whenever this happens, you might consider asking them why it needs to be more eye catching.

Posted a similar question sometime back that you might find useful
["Can you make it more prominent?" stakeholder phenomenon](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/108748/can-you-make-it-more-prominent-stakeholder-phenomenon)

Answer (score 0):

Generally describing an element in terms of Salience gets the point across. For example, a component that should really stand out should be described and designed as "Highly Salient" while something that should be more subtle should have "Low Salience".

The decision about what elements should have high/low salience (or anywhere in between) should be a 1:1 mapping of salience : information importance. Critically important information should be the MOST salient element of a display, while other elements, like land marking, labels, copyright statements, etc. should have low salience because they're generally not a part of a user's workflow (even if they must be present in the design).

As stated above, the best question to ask here is why that element needs to stand out so much? That answer will help you determine to what degree it should be more salient that the rest of the element/content in your design.

Comment: Not sure why this answer got a downvote. It is the exact term for this. "Visual salience (or visual saliency) is the distinct subjective perceptual quality which makes some items in the world stand out from their neighbors and immediately grab our attention." [Visual Salience](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Visual_salience)